PnP Powershell Connection with ClientId and ClientSecre return error "The app principal does not exist"
I'm trying to run my Powershell PnP script using ClientId and ClientSecret instead of UseWebLogin.
I already created an Azure Application ID using this tutorial (but skipping the certificate part for the moment):
https://yunusemrearac.medium.com/connecting-to-sharepoint-online-using-azure-ad-application-id-via-powershell-49191054ae40
This is my code:
#Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://myname.sharepoint.com/"

    Try {
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -ClientId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -ClientSecret "Sdf9Q~9pZErHkefW0Zt77IryFh-6vk_vI6B-Fch2"

Get-PnPsite

Disconnect-PnPOnline
 } 
 catch {  
     write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
 } 

I get this error:

Get-PnPsite : Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://myname.sharepoint.com/. The app principal does not exist.
At line:9 char:1

Using the UseWebLogin all is working.
What did I do wrong or miss in creating the Azure Application?

Don't you miss the -Tenant argument? For example: -Tenant 'myname.onmicrosoft.com'

No, -Tenant parameter does not exist when using -ClientSecret but it works if I use -Thumbprint, and at this point I wonder if -ClientSecret is usable here.

So maybe you're using AppId instead of ClientId... That's why you have the error The app principal does not exist.

If your code works with a cert, but does not work with a secret - I'd suspect a bug somewhere. I use Visual Studio Code, PowerShell 7 and PnP.PowerShell latest version (2.5 as of today).
For app (unattended) access:

if you are administering entire SharePoint - you'd have Sites.FullControl.All for both - Graph API and SharePoint API for full access to all sites.
if you need to work with one site only - use Sites.Selected permissions

It works just perfectly:
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientID -ClientSecret $clientSc


